# Rails ajax updating the UI on success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a simple posts page where users can create a new post - the form is ajax (and I'm working with turbolinks).

- What is the **Rails way** of updating the UI once the ajax succeeds ?

As I see it here are my options:

1. reload the page with javascript when ajax:success fires
2. In the Rails controller , return the new post as a json . Then on ajax:success I'll need to somehow create a template

e.g:

```
$("<div id='new-post'>").html(ajaxResult)
code to append the div to my posts
```

- Is this more or less the way to do it ? *(I'm not going to use ember or angular here)*
- Any reason to prefer the first or the second option?

Comment: option 2, update it through rails

Comment: Do people use handlebars.js for stuff like that or only when it's a really complicated UI?

Comment: for you purposes handlebars is overkill a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose option2 that is sending new as js and adding it to the div template using rails

for example:

**_form.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for(@model), :html => {remote: true} do |f| %>
        your input fields code here

 <% end %>
```

**controller.**

```
   def create
    respond_to do |format|
     if @model.save
        format.js
     else
         render 'new'
     end
     end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#get_input").html(<%= j ({render :partial => "create"})%>) **#get_input is your div id**
```

**_create.html.erb**

```
#write your template code here
```

Comment: Ah I like that I can just use my partials in that way and I don't need to build the html in my javascript , if I understand you correctly

Comment: @Joel_Blum to display partial data from ajax you need to append to some html element right.

Comment: Yep so all that's left is add append code to create.js.erb . I think its a reasonable solution if you don't need anything fancy

Answer (score 0):

there are lot's of ways you can do it :)

For ex. you can send not json but js request

```
def some_action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

then in your /views/../some_action.js.erb

```
$("<div id='new-post'>").html("<%=j({render here what you want}>")
```

Or you can really handle json. Then you need to use smth like https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets templates system and easily create js templates based on you JSON